# Does nonparametric bootstrapping work on correlated data?

Tags: estimation, bootstrap, point-estimation

I have $m$ weakly stationary observations $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_m$ from a Markov chain. I want to estimate the variance of the mean. My idea was to use nonparametric bootstrapping to make $n$ bootstrap samples from the $m$ observations and compute $n$ bootstrap means $\mu^*_i$. Then estimate the variance using
$$
\widehat{\mathrm{Var}(\overline X)} = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n ( \mu^*_i - \overline \mu^*)^2
$$
 Is it a problem that the observations are correlated, or is this fine?

Comment: By "unparameterised bootstrap" do you mean *nonparametric bootstrap* or are you referring to something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't use standard bootstrap. There are many dependent bootstraps.

Jens-Peter Kreiss, Efstathios Paparoditis, Bootstrap methods for dependent data: A review, Journal of the Korean Statistical Society, Volume 40, Issue 4, 2011, Pages 357-378, ISSN 1226-3192, Keywords: Stochastic processes; Bootstrap methods; Time series

[Here is a review](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1226319211000780) , [Here it is not behind paywall](http://mapageweb.umontreal.ca/goncals/documents/Goncalves-Politis-2011.pdf).